# Aero Shake disabled and window docking enabled + WinApi

Tags: winapi, aero, docking, shake

Could you help me with the problem below?

How can I disable the Aero Shake but window docking should work with using WinApi?

I know that these can off by winApi method **SystemParametersInfo** and **SPI_SETWINARRANGING**, but it disabled Aero  Shake and window docking.

The Aero Shake I can off 
in manual mode by Regedit or Local group Policy Editor and after that window docking will work.

I cannot find a solution how do it by WinApi.

Do somebody know a way for this?

Comment: It is a feature of the shell, it does not involve your program at all.  So no, only disabling it system-wide is possible.  Making it specific to your app's windows requires a sledge-hammer, you have to make the window borderless.  Also disables aero snap so you've got lots of ugly code to write.

Comment: I was inaccurate. 
I'd like to disable it for all system when my app is running. 
As I have wrote early, I can do it by WinApi with SPI.SPI_SETWINARRANGING

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx[DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(SPI uiAction, uint uiParam, ref bool pvParam, SPIF fWinIni);

But I'd like to disable Shake effect only and docking window docking will work.

It is possyble do by manual mode and I have hope  that this aslo can do from code by WinApi.