# How to disable Aero Shake minimize only on Windows 7

Tags: c++11, winapi, windows-7, aero

I need to disable AeroShake minimize while the rest Aero features still running. Fond only one solution:

```
SystemParametersInfo(0x0083, 0, 0, 1);
```

But this disables all Aero features. Found similar question [Aero Shake disabled and window docking enabled + WinApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50188170/aero-shake-disabled-and-window-docking-enabled-winapi) but no any answer behind.

How to disable Aero shake minimize only?

Answer (score 0):

> Aero Shake—a fun little feature that lets you grab a window by the
>   title bar and shake it to minimize all other open windows.

The following solution works for me on Windows 10 to disable the Shake (But I don't test other Aero features.). You can have a try to see if it helps.

Add a value named as `DisallowShaking` in Registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`. And change its value from 0 to 1. Like this:

[image]

Comment: @htonus Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863991/using-c-to-edit-the-registry) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-functions) for accessing registry in C++.