# Disable Aeroshake minimize by GPO

Tags: c++, winapi, aero, gpo

I'm trying to disable Aeroshake minimize mouse gesture only. Asked a question [How to disable Aero Shake minimize only on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57857902/how-to-disable-aero-shake-minimize-only-on-windows-7) but no answers. So I continued digging and found another solution by updating user Group Policy.

```
void aeroshake(DWORD action)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    IGroupPolicyObject* pLGPO;
    HKEY machine_key, dsrkey;
    LSTATUS sdf, ds, rStatus;
    GUID RegistryId = REGISTRY_EXTENSION_GUID;
    GUID ThisAdminToolGuid =
        /*{ CLSID_PolicySnapinUser/* */
    {
        0x0F6B957E,
        0x509E,
        0x11D1,
    { 0xA7, 0xCC, 0x00, 0x00, 0xF8, 0x75, 0x71, 0xE3 }
    };

    const IID my_IID_IGroupPolicyObject =
    { 0xea502723, 0xa23d, 0x11d1,{ 0xa7, 0xd3, 0x0, 0x0, 0xf8, 0x75, 0x71, 0xe3 } };
    const IID my_CLSID_GroupPolicyObject =
    { 0xea502722, 0xa23d, 0x11d1,{ 0xa7, 0xd3, 0x0, 0x0, 0xf8, 0x75, 0x71, 0xe3 } };
    GUID ext_guid = REGISTRY_EXTENSION_GUID;

    // This next one can be any GUID you want
    GUID snap_guid = { 0x3d271cfc, 0x2bc6, 0x4ac2,{ 0xb6, 0x33, 0x3b, 0xdf, 0xf5, 0xbd, 0xab, 0x2a } };

    // Create an instance of the IGroupPolicyObject class
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    CoCreateInstance(my_CLSID_GroupPolicyObject, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        my_IID_IGroupPolicyObject, (LPVOID*)&pLGPO);

    // We need the machine LGPO (if C++, no need to go through the lpVtbl table)
    hr = pLGPO->OpenLocalMachineGPO(GPO_OPEN_LOAD_REGISTRY);
    if (hr != S_OK) {
        goto release;
    }

    hr = pLGPO->GetRegistryKey(GPO_SECTION_USER, &machine_key);
    if (hr != S_OK) {
        goto close;
    }

    // create key for disable Aeroshake minimise
    sdf = RegCreateKeyEx(machine_key, TEXT("Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Desktop\\NoWindowMinimizingShortcuts"),
        0, NULL, 0, KEY_SET_VALUE | KEY_QUERY_VALUE, NULL, &dsrkey, NULL);

    // Create the value
    ds = RegSetKeyValue(dsrkey, NULL, TEXT("NoWindowMinimizingShortcuts"), REG_DWORD, &action, sizeof(action));
    RegCloseKey(dsrkey);

    // Apply policy and free resources
    pLGPO->Save( TRUE, TRUE, &ext_guid, &snap_guid);
    rStatus = RegCloseKey(machine_key);

    // Write the GPO back to the directory
    hr = pLGPO->Save(
        FALSE,
        TRUE,
        &RegistryId,
        &ThisAdminToolGuid);

close:
    RegCloseKey(machine_key);

release:
    pLGPO->Release();
}
```

This looks like a proper way but I have problem with `OpenLocalMachineGPO` it always returns `E_ACCESSDENIED`. Can that be sorted w/o need to run as Admin. Also when the code run as Admin it still doesn't change the required policy.

Answer (score 0):

`E_ACCESSDENIED` means no access, of course you need enough permissions to modify the GPO.

In addition, The key value `NoWindowMinimizingShortcuts` is under the Sub Key `Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Explorer`

```
sdf = RegCreateKeyEx(machine_key, TEXT("Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Explorer"),
        0, NULL, 0, KEY_SET_VALUE | KEY_QUERY_VALUE, NULL, &dsrkey, NULL);
```

You'll need to reboot or at least log off, then log in to take effect.(Even you modify in GPO directly)

Then the changes will be updated to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`:

NoWindowMinimizingShortcuts = 0x00000001

Of course, you can also modify this key directly.(need to create it first if you don't have one)

```
void aeroshake(DWORD action)
{
    // create key for disable Aeroshake minimise
    HKEY hKeyRoot, dsrkey;
    LSTATUS sdf = RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows"), &hKeyRoot);
    sdf = RegCreateKey(hKeyRoot, TEXT("Explorer"), &dsrkey);
    // Create the value
    sdf = RegSetKeyValue(dsrkey, NULL, TEXT("NoWindowMinimizingShortcuts"), REG_DWORD, &action, sizeof(action));
    RegCloseKey(dsrkey);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I looked through the tons of the articles and they state that changes in GPO take effect immediately while the changes in the Registry wants reload of the user session. Moreover changes in GPO overwrite the values in the Registry.

Comment: As far as I know, Windows periodically refreshes group policy settings throughout the network. On client computers, this is done by default every 90 minutes, with a randomized offset of plus or minus 30 minutes. You can use [gpupdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/gpupdate) to manually refresh.

Comment: After testing, I found that even if I directly modify `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`, it will not take effect immediately.